# Insert multiple values in hashSet Java

Tags: java

The idea is to set different values from one class to another using the  interface.

My code:

```
public Make(String name, int foundingYear, String founder) {
    this.name = name;
    this.foundingYear = foundingYear;
    this.founder = founder;
}
//other code
```

So I want to set those values in another class like this:

```
public record anotherClass (String name, String color, int hp) {

Make make = new Make();
Set<Make> makes = new HashSet<>();
makes.add("name", 1995, "founder");
```

The thing is when I'm trying to add values (`makes.add("name", 1995, "founder");`) I can't do that, because it expects just one argument to be added of type `makes`. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: `make.add(new Make("name", 1995, "founder"));` and remove the now useless `Make make = new Make();`

Comment: you are passing the parameters for the constructor instead of an invoked constructor to which you pass those parameters

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca >> OMG Federico, you saved my life! :D I've been searching for that answer for the last two hours. Thanks! :)

Comment: You might want to revisit the tutorial on collections as well as objects and their creation.  A collection contains elements it gets from somewhere but how those elements are created is unknown to a collection (and it doesn't care). Thus `makes.add("name", 1995, "founder");` wouldn't make sense as `makes` expects instances of `Make` and doesn't care about the constructor or properties in that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must instantiate Make using the 3 params, then add this make into the Set. See below:

```
Make make = new Make("name", 1995, "founder"); // use this make
Set<Make> makes = new HashSet<>();
makes.add(make);
```